# Any ideas for useful(not for fun) Android applications?

Tags: android

I am studying in Android programming and would like to develop an useful Android application for my project, but I still could't get any good ideas after searching on the internet.
Any suggestions that an app is useful in our dailylife even achieve the society such as about public health, education, security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about an [intelligent mobile health care system](http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJCA/vol2_no3/2.pdf) you can write an android app instead of the j2me app mentioned here.

Comment: It sounds great but seems difficult for me, because I still don't understand how it works totally (sorry for my poor english).

Comment: The idea of health care sytem maybe more suitable for the project, I will consider to write a simply version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An application that detects if you are in trouble (being kipnapped, etc) using different sensors to detect struggling, shouts... and then call the police and start ringing at a very loud volume.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think it is difficult to analysis the struggling and shouts correctly to determine whether in dangers.